# Vuex: add to prototype so I can do something like object.save()?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

All my Vuex modules use base `UPSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` functions so I would love to not type `this.$store.dispatch('UPSERT', object)` in my components and instead type `object.save()`. I assume this is easy, but not sure if there are any issues with doing this or how to do this.

```js
    export interface ITaskMessage {
      id?: string
      message: string | null
      save(): any
    }
    
    export class TaskMessage implements ITaskMessage {
      id?: string
      message: string | null = ''
      save() {
        window._actions['UPSERT']
      }
    }
```

This code is from **types.ts** inside  a module. I assume I need to import something in this file and then use that inside the class declaration. I'm just not sure what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than I was making it out to be. Basically, import the store into the file:

```
import store from '@/store'
```

Then, fill in the save method:

```
  public save() {
    store.dispatch('UPSERT', this)
  }
```